# Service loading: how to write plugins on Kotlin native?

Tags: java, kotlin, plugins, serviceloader

In Java you are able to write plugins for your application with [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

In this case you can define:
`interface A` and `class B implements A` and simply in your code do the following:

1. Create an external plugin with a configuration, where you will define, that your class B is implementing this interface;
2. Load the proper implementation of a plugin, that will be taken from a configuration with `ServiceLoader.load(A::class.java)`;
3. Work with **implementation** B of interface A;

**But what to do when I try to load external plugin on the runtime of a Kotlin native application?** 
Is there any libraries or any chance to inject external code in the same way as it is done with ServiceLoader on the runtime?